# Why Length of values does not match length of index?

Tags: python, pandas

**Why I keep getting this error on Labels?**

```
# Appending Clustered Labels
#neighborhoods_venues_sorted.insert(0, 'Cluster Labels', kmeans.labels_)
lahore_merged = df_data_0
# add clustering labels
lahore_merged['Labels'] = kmeans.labels_
lahore_merged = lahore_merged.join(neighborhoods_venues_sorted.set_index('Neighborhood'), on='Neighborhood')
lahore_merged.head() # check the last columns!
```

**ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index**

Comment: what is the complete error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete error message would be useful but at a first look, it looks like the index of the `lahore_merged` and the length of `kmeans.labels_` are different. Can you check that they are the same?